# Hibernate - Unable to resolve connection default schema: Unable to use Java 1.7 Connection#getSchema

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

### Summary

While trying to save items to database i faced an issue, that hibernate creates tables with correct columns, but never populates them. I assume there is a problem with obtaining default schema in some cases, but the cause is spring, driver or hibernate itself?

stacktrace:

```
""2019-01-28 12:49:31 - Database ->
       name : PostgreSQL
    version : 10.6
      major : 10
      minor : 6
""2019-01-28 12:49:31 - Driver ->
       name : PostgreSQL Native Driver
    version : PostgreSQL 9.1 JDBC4 (build 901)
      major : 9
      minor : 1
""2019-01-28 12:49:31 - JDBC version : 4.0
""2019-01-28 12:49:31 - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
""2019-01-28 12:49:31 - Unable to use Java 1.7 Connection#getSchema
""2019-01-28 12:49:31 - Unable to resolve connection default schema
"org.hibernate.HibernateException: Use of DefaultSchemaNameResolver requires Dialect to provide the proper SQL statement/command but provided Dialect [org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect] did not return anything from Dialect#getCurrentSchemaCommand
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.DefaultSchemaNameResolver$SchemaNameResolverFallbackDelegate.resolveSchemaName(DefaultSchemaNameResolver.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.DefaultSchemaNameResolver.resolveSchemaName(DefaultSchemaNameResolver.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.determineCurrentSchemaName(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.<init>(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:232)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:615)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:224)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1112)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1079)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:580)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:543)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:711)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:684)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:356)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:273)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at ru.legionofone.klassikaplusserver.KlassikaplusServerApplication.main(KlassikaplusServerApplication.java:15)
```

### Background:

This is a backend server for a mobile app, tipical heroku free dyno.
Using postgreSQL 10.0.
Problem reproduces on both local environment and on heroku dyno.

POM.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ru.legionofone</groupId>
    <artifactId>klassikaplusserver</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>klassikaplusserver</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>9</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.55</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.intellij/annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intellij</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>12.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>9</source>
                    <target>9</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

### Code

I've tried to configure hibernate with different dialects, but it does not change a thing. Also tried to persist items with session or entity manager, no success either.

**HibernateConf**

```
import org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConf {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HibernateConf.class);

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("ru.legionofone.klassikaplusserver.model.persistance");
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        String dbUrl = System.getenv("JDBC_DATABASE_URL");
        String username = System.getenv("JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME");
        String password = System.getenv("JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD");

        logger.info(new StringBuilder()
                .append("Starting server on database: ")
                .append("URL: ").append(dbUrl).append(";")
                .append("User ").append(username).append(";")
                .append("Password ").append(password).append(";")
                .toString());

        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl(dbUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    private final Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("ShowSqlEnabled", "true");
//        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.default_schema", "public");
//        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.autocommit", "true");

        return hibernateProperties;
    }
}
```

**Dao**

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class AbstractHibernateDao<T extends Serializable> {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AbstractHibernateDao.class);
    protected Class<T> clazz;

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public final void setClazz(Class<T> clazzToSet) {
        this.clazz = clazzToSet;
    }

    public T findOne(long id) {
        logger.info("Getting entity " + clazz.getName() + "\n id: " + id);
        return (T) getCurrentSession().get(clazz, id);
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        logger.info("Find All entities " + clazz.getName());
        return getCurrentSession().createQuery("from " + clazz.getName()).list();
    }

    public void create(T entity) {
        logger.info("Creating entity" + clazz.getName());
        getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
        getCurrentSession().persist(entity);
        getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
//        entityManager.persist(entity);
//        entityManager.detach(entity);
//        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public void update(T entity) {
        logger.info("Merging entity" + clazz.getName());
        getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
        getCurrentSession().merge(entity);
        getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public void delete(T entity) {

        logger.info("Deleting entity" + clazz.getName());
        getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
        getCurrentSession().delete(entity);
        getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public void deleteById(long entityId) {
        logger.info("Deleting entity " + clazz.getName() + "\n id: " + entityId);
        T entity = findOne(entityId);
        getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
        delete(entity);
        getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
    }

    protected final Session getCurrentSession() {
//        if (entityManager != null ) {
//            return entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().unwrap(SessionFactory.class).getCurrentSession();
//        } else {
//            logger.error("Failed to obtain session factory");
//            throw new NullPointerException(); // FIXME: 1/28/2019
//        }
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
}
```

PS:
I'm not quite sure, but this might be the bug:
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11424?jql=Participants%20%3D%20bvarner
In this case, any recommendations?

Comment: Why are you using such an outdated (and obsolete) JDBC driver which is known to not work with Postgres 10?

Comment: I've tried _<version>42.2.5</version>_ with no success. Getting the same error.

Comment: Why is your title Java 1.7 and you are setting  <java.version>9</java.version> (which is a deprecated version of Java) and using Spring Boot 2.1, which only supports Java 8+? You should fix these issues before diagnosing why things don't work. Either baseline on Java 8 or 11.

Comment: Also please read the documentation on how to connect to a database using Spring Boot. It should be around 4 lines of configuration. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html

Comment: @AlexB Java 1.7 in my title is because thats the error i get from the stack trace.

Comment: @AlexB I used this [tutorial] (https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-5-spring) to configure DataSource for hibernate. After your comment i used DataSourceBuilder class to make a datasource bean, and it fixed the error. Many thanks!

Comment: @fred shmorgilov That tutorial is for Spring. You're using Spring Boot, which automatically creates all that manual configuration. Try reading the documentation I linked to, and you can replace manual configuration with ~4 lines of properties. You should also either use Java 8 or Java 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, with some help i was able to figure it out.

What helped:
1) In DataSource bean replaced SimpleDataSource with DataSourceBuilder.build();
2) Added @Transactional annotation for all methods in Dao class.